# Change color of span text but not on the :before (or :after)

Tags: html, css, sass

**As the title says: is there a way to change the color of the span text without changing its `:before` and `:after` colors as well?**

Why? I've got this component (see below) and want to give it another color (but not the xp badge) when it has a certain class on it.

html:

```
<span class="xp">509</span>
```

sass:

```
  span.xp
    font-size: 10px
    color: #f5f8f9

    &:after
      content: "xp"
      display: inline
      background: $sidebar-background
      font-size: 8px
      font-weight: bold
      padding: 1px 3px
      border-radius: 2px
      vertical-align: 6%
```

Comment: Not without explicitly stating a different color. `color` is inherited by children (and pseudo-children).

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest solution, but it technically works:

```
  span.xp
    font-size: 10px
    color: #f5f8f9

    &:after
      color: #000
      content: "xp"
      display: inline
      background: $sidebar-background
      font-size: 8px
      font-weight: bold
      padding: 1px 3px
      border-radius: 2px
      vertical-align: 6%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Span.xp:after {
        Content: "]";
        Color: black;
    }
   Span.xp:before {
       Content: "[";
       Color: black;
   }
       span.xp{
       color: #ff00pp;
   }
```

With sass
Use something like this

```
span.xp 
  font-size: 10px 
  color: #ff00pp

    &:after 
      content: "xp" 
     color: #000
     display: inline background:    $sidebar-background font-size: 8px font-weight: bold padding: 1px 3px border-radius: 2px vertical-align: 6%
```